# copy/paste using wsl tmux ssh vim

Tags: windows, vim, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tmux

The main goal is to have a really really global copy/paste system using wsl+tmux+ssh+vim.

I need to work with Windows with WSL inside I start the Tmux inside tmux I start creating some windows, each window is one SSH session to a different machine, inside the SSH sessions I open VIM, where I need to copy/paste content from one session to another and sometimes copy/paste from my computer to the ssh session and the other way round.

What I have is WSL > TMUX > SSH's > Vim's

So... how to get a full global copy/paste system with VIM keyboards so yy copy line and p to paste on another ssh session with vim opened in it and sometimes I want to copy/paste from windows to ssh sessions.

---

What I have so far.. I can use xclip in tmux+wsl to get global/copy paste

```
# Set mode vi
# Use 'v'/'Space' to start selection and 'Enter' to end, use 'q' to exit selection mode
setw -g mode-keys vi
bind -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection
bind -T copy-mode-vi r send-keys -X rectangle-toggle

# Make Home & End keys work in copy mode
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'Home' send -X start-of-line
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'End' send -X end-of-line

# Yank selection in copy mode, copy to windows clipboard, cancel copy mode
bind -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel clip.exe
bind -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel clip.exe
bind -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel clip.exe
```

If I want the global copy/paste between VIM and WSL I need the following approach

```
1. Install gvim or vim-gtk 
2. alias vim='gvim -v'
3. vim --version | grep -e 'clipboard' # desired +clipboard and +xterm_clipboard
4. Install VcXsrv
5. Generate the config.xlaunch file by opening XLaunch, select default options, be sure clipboard options are enabled
6. Add the config.xlaunch to startup of Windows, %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

on ~/.vimrc
" Enable global copy/paste Unix and Windows
set clipboard^=unnamed,unnamedplus
```

Problems I identified: when copy/pasting from ssh sessions with y inside vim and pasting in another ssh session with vim, it's pasting another content from the machine clipboard I think.

If more info is needed or if I need to clarify something please inform me.

If you recommend another tools/workflows I'm open to it.

Comment: You question has two votes to move it to the superuser site. This is not exactly a programming question so that might be the right thing to do but there's a lot of gray area. The downvote most likely is for posting on the wrong site, don't worry to much about it.

Comment: thank you for explaining, now I understood, I will try to ask in the right place, sorry for that @LievenKeersmaekers